# destroy services objects and instantiate them again

Tags: symfony, phpunit

Actually in my api I've got a command which processes a file and update the db accordingly. To highlight the diffrence between creating and updating I've added a property into my service (which takes true or false for create and update).

This works fine, but when I tried to create the unittest for that, the property looks like it keeps the last value when I run again the my command.

How can I destroy my service object in order to force it to reload itself?

**EDIT**

```
class MyServiceClass
{
      // My attribute
      private creation=true;

      // My service dependencies
      public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $s)
      {
                $this->container = $s;
      }

      public function getContainer()
      {
                return $this->container;
      }
      // ....
```

Comment: How/where do you declare your creating/updating property in your service ?

Comment: In my class of the service, since a service is a class. This attribute is a boolean variable (private creation=true).

Comment: Can you edit your post to show your class ?

Comment: You are getting your service via the container?  If so, set the scope property to prototype to get get a fresh instance each time. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

Comment: However, since unit tests really should be independent, I suspect your really want to start from scratch using the unit setup method.

Comment: @Cerad you're right, I need a fresh instance each time only with unit tests.

Comment: how can I inject the my service into my unit test file? (without using container of course)

Comment: @Cerad how can I do it from scratch?